# Adding "extends AnyVal" causes a "type arguments do no conform" error

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

In Scala 2.10, this works:

```
implicit class T1[A](val self: Iterator[A]) {
  def :+[B >: A](elem: B): Iterator[B] =
    self ++ Iterator(elem)
}
```

But when I try to make it a value class:

```
implicit class T2[A](val self: Iterator[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def :+[B >: A](elem: B): Iterator[B] =
    self ++ Iterator(elem)  
}
```

I get the error:

```
type arguments [B] do not conform to method ++'s type parameter bounds [B >: A]
```

Why?

Comment: Strangely I ran into the same bug today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug and it is already fixed in the current nightly.

See [this ticket](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7022) for more information.